# Discretize differential equation by finite differences. What is the matrix?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have a differential equation:
$$ -u''(x) + \sigma u'(x) = f(x), \quad 0<x<1$$ with boundary conditions $u(0) = \alpha$ and $u(1) = \beta$.
I've discretized equation using symmetric (finite) differences:
$$ \frac{-u_{i-1} + 2u_i - u_{i+1}}{h^2} + \sigma \frac{u_{i+1} - u_i}{h} = f_i $$
If $n$ is the number of discretization points,  $h = \frac{1}{n+1}$.

My question is how would I get that in a matrix form $Ax = f$ ?

Comment: Is the question about discretizing your boundary conditions? Because otherwise you have a bunch of linear equations, so technically they are "already" in matrix form as soon as you "choose a basis" (which would obviously be corresponding to $\{ u_0, u_1, \cdots, u_n \}$ here). Can you develop on your issue? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: No, I just want to see the matrix form. Because when I run some iterative numerical method (for example SSOR) I get different solution than when I run SOR. So now I'm getting confused if I wrote my matrix right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you want $u(0) = \alpha$ and $u(1) = \beta$, not $u(a) = \beta$. Anyway, in the discretized version I'm guessing it means $u_0 = \alpha$ and $u_n = \beta$. So in fact you only want to solve for $u_1,\cdots, u_{n-1}$. I'll write $N = n+1$ just to not write $+1$'s everywhere. The first equation (for $u_1$) tells you that
$$
N^2(-u_0 + 2u_1 - u_2) + N \sigma (u_2 - u_1) = f_1,
$$
i.e.
$$
(2N^2 - \sigma N) u_1 + (-N^2 + N \sigma)u_2 = f_1 + N u_0 = f_1 + N^2 \alpha.
$$
For $u_{n-1}$, you have the equation
$$
N^2 (-u_{n-2} + 2u_{n-1} - u_n) + N \sigma (u_n - u_{n-1}) = f_{n-1},
$$
i.e. 
$$
(-N^2) u_{n-2} + (2N^2 - N \sigma) u_{n-1} = f_{n-1} + (N^2 - N \sigma) u_n = f_{n-1} + (N^2 - N \sigma) \beta.
$$
For the other equations, you get 
$$
N^2(-u_{i-1} + 2 u_i - u_{i+1}) + N\sigma (u_{i+1} - u_i) = f_i,
$$
i.e.
$$
(-N^2) u_{i-1} + (2N^2 - N \sigma) u_i + (-N^2 + N \sigma) u_{i+1} = f_i.
$$

To put all these equations in a clean form, let 
$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0  & \cdots & & \\
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & & \\
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & \cdots &  \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\ 
\\
 & & & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &  \\
 & & & & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
 & & & & & -1 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and 
$$
B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1  &        &        &   \\
   & -1 & 1      &        &   \\
   &    & \ddots & \ddots &   \\
   &    &        & -1     & 1 \\
   &    &        &        & -1 
\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Then letting $u = \begin{bmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \\ \vdots \\ u_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}$, you're looking to solve 
$$
(N^2 A + N \sigma B) u = F,
$$
where
$$
F = \begin{bmatrix} f_1 + N^2 \alpha \\ f_2 \\ \vdots \\ f_{n-2} \\ f_{n-1} + (N^2 - N \sigma) \beta \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Hope that helps,

Comment: Exactly what I needed, exactly! Thank you

Comment: To clarify, N should be 1/(n+1) ?

Comment: @Caley : I explained in the answer why $N = n+1$! Do you see a problem in the answer?